# How to implement observer pattern without having to bind to a specific class?

Tags: c++, c++11, observer-pattern

I want to observe an object being deleted at the function level.  In other words, I would say inside of a function, observe that object and allow me to interrogate something to know if it has gotten deleted.  When the function is done, don't observe it anymore.

This is my current API:

```
template <typename T>
class DeleteReporter
{
    std::pair<T*, bool>* obj_deleted_pair;
public:
    DeleteReporter(T* pObject);
    operator bool();
    ~DeleteReporter();
};

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter<T> make_DeleteReporter(T* pObject);

template <typename T>
void MarkDeleted(T* pObject);
```

And here is the implementation:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::pair<T*, bool>>& obj_deleted_pairs()
{
    static std::vector<std::pair<T*, bool>> obj_deleted_pairs;
    return obj_deleted_pairs;
}

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter<T> make_DeleteReporter(T* pObject)
{
    return DeleteReporter<T>(pObject);
}

template <typename T>
void MarkDeleted(T* pObject)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(obj_deleted_pairs<T>().begin(), obj_deleted_pairs<T>().end()
        , [pObject](std::pair<T*, bool>& obj_deleted_pair)
        {
            return obj_deleted_pair.first == pObject;
        });
    if (it != obj_deleted_pairs<T>().end())
    {
        it->second = true;
    }
}

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter::DeleteReporter(T* pObject)
{
    obj_deleted_pairs<T>().emplace_back(pObject, false);
    obj_deleted_pair = &*obj_deleted_pairs<T>().rbegin();
}

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter::operator bool()
{
    return obj_deleted_pair->second;
}

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter::~DeleteReporter()
{
    obj_deleted_pairs<T>().erase(obj_deleted_pairs<T>().begin()
        + std::distance(&*obj_deleted_pairs<T>().begin(), obj_deleted_pair));
}
```

To use, there would be a call in the destructor to `MarkDeleted()` with `this` passed to it.  Then in the function, it would instantiate `DeleteReporter` using `make_DeleteReporter()` passing the object to observe.  Later, the `DeleteReporter` object would be queried to ensure that the object didn't get deleted sometime after the instantiation before trying to talk to it.

Originally, I didn't have this as a template, but instead the functions had taken `void*`.  I then realised that, if the object was multiply inherited, it is possible that the pointer may not properly match.

Implementing using a template as I've done will also cause this to happen as the pointer may be in the wrong `vector`.  I could specifically state the type, but I would rather have the compiler determine this.  So my question is, is there some way to traverse the inheritance tree to find the object?  Or maybe there is some other way this can be done?

I also would rather not have to add additional functions and members to the  classes to observe.  I have thought of that, but would like it if I could have a cleaner separation.

Comment: `obj_deleted_pair = &*obj_deleted_pairs<T>().rbegin();` Danger, Will Robinson! Adding to a vector may invalidate all pointers, references and iterators to existing elements of the vector. Creating a new instance of `DeleteReporter` may leave all other still-alive instances holding dangling pointers.

Comment: Also, it's possible that an object is created, destroyed, and then another object is created in its place, with the same address (and then also eventually destroyed). In this case, you'll have two pairs with the same pointer on the vector, but `MarkDeleted` will only update the first one, twice.

Comment: Erasing from vector (as `~DeleteReporter` does) also invalidates all pointers references and iterators to the erased element and all elements that follow.

Comment: `DeleteReporter` doesn't provide a copy constructor, and a compiler-generated one would simply copy over `obj_deleted_pair`. So you may end up with two or more instances of `DeleteReporter`, each holding the same pointer and each `erase`ing it from the vector when destroyed, which guarantees undefined behavior. Furthermore, `make_DeleteReporter` returns by value, virtually guaranteeing that a copy will in fact be made (though you might be lucky and get saved by RVO).

Comment: I don't see why you need a stateful object at all. Just as `MarkDeleted` is a standalone function, you can have `WatchForDeletion` and `CheckIfDeleted` as standalone functions. Your `DeleteReporter` is nothing but trouble.

Comment: If the pointer you have in hand is to a polymorphic base class (a class with at least one virtual function), then `dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` would give you a pointer to the most-derived object - a unique identity of the object (for as long as it's alive; as I said, memory may be reused for a different object after this one dies). Apart from that, there's no general way to obtain object identity (which is what your problem seems to boil down to).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `I don't see why you need a stateful object at all. ... Your DeleteReporter is nothing but trouble`  - I disagree.  If you have a `WatchForDeletion` function, then you would need a symmetrical `StopWatchingForDeletion` function, which then lends itself to a state variable.  I think that when implemented correctly, this is a good solution, though using `shared_ptr`'s everywhere for the observing the object in question would have been a better one, but this is an addon to an already existing complex system, which I would rather touch as minimally as possible.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `Furthermore, make_DeleteReporter returns by value, virtually guaranteeing that a copy will in fact be made (though you might be lucky and get saved by RVO)`.  Yes, I was counting on RVO.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `If the pointer you have in hand is to a polymorphic base class (a class with at least one virtual function), then dynamic_cast<void*>(p) would give you a pointer to the most-derived object`.  Yeah, I thought of that and didn't want to do that.  `Apart from that, there's no general way to obtain object identity `  I concur.  The solution I posted deals with all of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a chance to see the comments that @Igor gave till now, but last night I was thinking about this and I deemed that it wasn't possible to determine the correct list, so I'm not bothering and stating that the user must know what type to watch for.

I also thought of the same errors as @Igor stated and then some.  Here is the final implementation that I am using:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define _AFXDLL  // required if using the MFC DLL and not a static implementation
#include <afx.h> // used for the ASSERT() macro
// DeleteReporter
//
// DESCRIPTION
//   This class is to warn a function that at somepoint in its execution, the
//   object of interest has been deleted.
//
// USAGE
//   To use, add the function call MarkDeleted(this); to the end of the 
//   destructor of the type you wish to test for.
//
//   In the function that you want to check for the destruction, create a 
//   DeleteReporter<T> variable, where T is the type where you added the
//   MarkDeleted(this) to.
//
//   You can now query the object you created to determine if the object of
//   interest has been deleted.
//
//   Example:
//
//   C::~C()
//   {
//     ...
//
//     MarkDeleted(this);
//   }
//
//   void C::fn()
//   {
//      ...
//
//      DeleteReporter<C> C_Deleted(this);
//
//      ... do stuff ...
//
//      if (!C_Deleted)
//      {
//        ... call member functions ...
//      }
//
//      ...
//   }
//
//                                            By: Adrian Hawryluk January 2017
template <typename T>
void MarkDeleted(T* pObject);

template <typename T>
class DeleteReporter
{
    friend void MarkDeleted<T>(T* pObject);
    using        pair_t = std::pair<T*, bool>;
    using shared_pair_t = std::shared_ptr<pair_t>;
    struct vector_t;

    static vector_t obj_deleted_pairs;

    shared_pair_t obj_deleted_pair;
public:
    DeleteReporter(T* pObject);
    DeleteReporter(DeleteReporter const &)  = delete;
    DeleteReporter(DeleteReporter       &&) = delete;
    operator bool();
    ~DeleteReporter();
};




//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implementation

template <typename T>
void MarkDeleted(T* pObject)
{
    using      vector_t = typename DeleteReporter<T>::vector_t;
    using shared_pair_t = typename DeleteReporter<T>::shared_pair_t;
    vector_t& obj_deleted_pairs = DeleteReporter<T>::obj_deleted_pairs;
    for (shared_pair_t& obj_deleted_pair : obj_deleted_pairs)
    {
        if (obj_deleted_pair->first == pObject)
        {
            obj_deleted_pair->second = true;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct DeleteReporter<T>::vector_t : std::vector<shared_pair_t>
{
    ~vector_t()
    {
        // When deleting the storage vector, it should be empty, or there's an error
        ASSERT(size() == 0);
    }
};

template <typename T>
typename DeleteReporter<T>::vector_t DeleteReporter<T>::obj_deleted_pairs;

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter<T>::DeleteReporter(T* pObject)
{
    obj_deleted_pair = std::make_shared<pair_t>(pObject, false);
    obj_deleted_pairs.emplace_back(obj_deleted_pair);
}

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter<T>::operator bool()
{
    return obj_deleted_pair->second;
}

template <typename T>
DeleteReporter<T>::~DeleteReporter()
{
    auto& it = std::find(obj_deleted_pairs.begin(), obj_deleted_pairs.end(), obj_deleted_pair);
    obj_deleted_pairs.erase(it);
}
```